# wordpress - ALL pages

Tags: wordpress

The columns for both posts and pages (in standard view) have shifted one to the right, so are not under the correct headers. See image.

So for example, the title is no longer under the title column and the author is no longer under the author column etc...

i believe it may have something to so with "manage_posts_columns", but dont know how to fix this nor what caused it.

How can the user correct this ?

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you told us what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: One of your plugins (or even the theme) is bugged

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  So having removed all the plugins and re-install one-by-one it appears as though the `Atomic Blocks - Gutenberg Blocks Collection` plugin causes this error.

I have not looked into why, but disabling resolves.